# How get estimated block with timestamp

Tags: bsc

So for example, I want to enable my contract 1 week after deployment, thats now() + 1 week,
how could I know which block that will be so I can send my clients a countdown to that block with
https://bscscan.com/block/countdown/9999999

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any library to estimate timestamp of future block?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71111/is-there-any-library-to-estimate-timestamp-of-future-block)

Answer (score 1):

Since block time varies, I would suggesting selecting a block that would be somewhere in that timebox.
And it would make perfect sense to announce ie. contract is active from block xxxxxxxx
If you need some stuff to prepare before exact timestamp give yourself some more time then calculated

Answer (score 0):

On BSC blocks are validated every 3 seconds. So that's 201600 blocks per week. You could just add 201600 to the block number where you contract was deployed.

Comment: How accurate is this, can you please ellaborate if/how the block generation speed is going to change over time (assuming no changes on the blockchain codebase, no forks/hardforks)?

Comment: I this accurate as far as this is how it is described in bsc documentation, and I haven't seen a block that was not 3 sec apart from the previous block. However, I have no idea if this will change or not.

Answer (score 0):

We built a little tool for this last year called BlockBucket:

https://blockbucket.io/block-calculator

It works by using the average block times and figuring out how many blocks it will take to get to that time. We've built it to work for most EVM chains (including BSC).

Hopefully this should do the trick?

Let me know if you have any questions :)